# Data is posting but not going into the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to save HTML from a contenteditable DIV into the database. The data are posting fine but at the database insertion, they are `nil`.

Here's my log:

```
Started POST "/pages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-29 18:39:01 +0800
Processing by PagesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"yAkOgEXN1Xq6Aiu6thcODiji7rs0SYA07/83XkQ2sBM=", "title"=>"Untitled Page", "live"=>"1", "content"=>"%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22page%20last-page-active%22%20style%3D%22height%3A%20576px%3B%20%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22page-element%20page-element-textbox%20ui-draggable%20ui-resizable%20ui-resizable-disabled%20ui-state-disabled%22%20style%3D%22left%3A%201256px%3B%20top%3A%2080px%3B%20width%3A%20272px%3B%20%22%20aria-disabled%3D%22true%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22page-element-content%22%20contenteditable%3D%22true%22%3E%3Ch2%3EUntitled%20Page%3C/h2%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ui-resizable-handle%20ui-resizable-e%22%20style%3D%22display%3A%20none%3B%20%22%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22ui-resizable-handle%20ui-resizable-w%22%20style%3D%22display%3A%20none%3B%20%22%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/div%3E"}
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO `pages` (`content`, `created_at`, `live`, `title`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", nil], ["created_at", Sun, 29 Apr 2012 10:39:01 UTC +00:00], ["live", nil], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Sun, 29 Apr 2012 10:39:01 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.9ms)  COMMIT
```

This is my controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pages = Page.all
    @page = Page.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  # index.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @pages }
    end
  end

  def new
    @page = Page.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  # new.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @page }
    end
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.new(params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.save
        format.html  { redirect_to(@page,
                      :notice => 'Page was successfully created.') }
        format.json  { render :json => @page,
                      :status => :created, :location => @page }
      else
        format.html  { render :action => "new" }
        format.json  { render :json => @page.errors,
                      :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  # show.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @page }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: are you that the your index action is correct one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@page = Page.new(params[:page])
```

should be

```
@page = Page.new(params)
```

You can see it in your console output:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "title"=>"Untitled Page", "live"=>"1", "content"=>"..."}
```

If `params[:page]` would be correct, you will see:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "page"=>{"title"=>"Untitled Page", "live"=>"1", "content"=>"..."}}
```

Comment: Cool thanks! I fixed it by placing the attributes within a "page" property. The authenticity_token property has to be top level though.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is expecting `params[:page]` to be a hash containing the values to create the page with. However your form is submitting all those parameters at the top level, as you can see from the log file excerpt.

You should change your form, so that the parameters appear inside `params[:page]`, for example the title input should be named `page[title]`. If you use `form_for` and the rails helps (`f.text_field`, `f.check_box` etc.) you get this for free.